# Mask 8 bit value into 32 bit value

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I have a 8 bit value that I want to store in an existing 32 bit value, while only updating the data on 8 bits and keeping the other 24 bits as they were before.

For example I might want to store 0x01 (0x00000001) into the existing value 0x01000100 and I want the result to be 0x01000101.

My first thought was to OR in 0xFFFFFF00 to the 8 bit value I want to store to make it 0xFFFFFFXX. Then I was gonna AND that to the 32 bit value, but I realized that it won't work if the 32 bit value has 00 as the last byte and I want to store 01. Then I thought I would just use my original 8 bit value and OR it directly into the 32 bit value, but that won't work if the last byte in the 32 bit value is 01 and I want to store 00.

I realize that this might be a bit hard to read but basically what I want to do is to merge a 32 bit value of 0xXXXXXXXX and a 8 bit value of 0xYY (0x000000YY) to become 0xXXXXXXYY

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got pretty close: First, zero out the lowermost bytes of your target 32-bit value by AND'ing with 0xFFFFFF00, and then, OR in your eight-bit value.

Comment: "and then, OR in your eight-bit value" special care have to be taken to mask out the first 3 bytes of the eight-bit through an AND operation with 0x000000FF mask

Comment: @redobot: I was assuming that only the lower eight bits are set - but indeed, it is safer to do as you and MikeCAT say.

Answer (score 4):

```
x = 0xXXXXXXXX;
y = 0x000000YY;
ret = (x & 0xFFFFFF00) | (y & 0x000000FF);
```